# Inherit models whith seperate primary key in django model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a abstract model which I want all of my models inherit from it:

```
from django.db import models


class Audit(models.Model):
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modify_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    create_by = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)
    last_modify_by = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        abstract: True
```

now fro example I have two models:

```
from general.AuditableModel import Audit


class Province(Audit):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'province_v2'
        verbose_name_plural = _('provinces')
        verbose_name = _('province')


class City(Audit):
    province_id = models.ForeignKey('address.Province', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cities')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'city_v2'
        verbose_name_plural = _('cities')
        verbose_name = _('city')
```

in my database it makes tables like this:

```
create table province_v2
(
    audit_ptr_id integer     not null
        primary key
        references general_audit
            deferrable initially deferred,
    name         varchar(30) not null
);

create table city_v2
(
    audit_ptr_id   integer     not null
        primary key
        references general_audit
            deferrable initially deferred,
    name           varchar(30) not null,
    province_id_id integer     not null
        references province_v2
            deferrable initially deferred
);

create index city_v2_province_id_id_12975070
    on city_v2 (province_id_id);
```

but I want my models have independent
`id integer primary key`
without abstract  table, now it made general_audit table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You by accident made a *non-abstract* model. Indeed, in order to assign a variable, you use the equation sybol (`=`). You used a colon instead (`:`). This means you made a *real* table in the database for `Audit`, and thus used Django's inheritance mechanism.

You thus should write `abstract = True`:

```
class Audit(models.Model):
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modify_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    create_by = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)
    last_modify_by = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        # not :
        abstract = True
```